# I am unable to get xpath of the following html code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to get XPath of the following HTML code but

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException
```

error occurs

I tried this -

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[@href='#home']")).click();
```

HTML

```
<a class="nav-link active show" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
  <svg class="olymp-register-icon">
    <use xlink:href="top10allthings.com/theme/app/svg-icons/sprites/…">
      <svg id="olymp-register-icon" viewBox="0 0 37 32">
        <title> register-icon </title>
      </svg>
    </use>
  </svg>
  <div class="ripple-container"> </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can right click and copy xpath in chrome

Comment: @KevinGlasson, I did the same as you told me but it gives me following error

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a class="nav-link " data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">...</a> is not clickable at point (560, 358). Other element would receive the click: <div id="hellopreloader" style="opacity: 0.0686328;">...</div>

Comment: Please provide the code sample text instead of the image. Do update the question with the complete error messages.

Comment: I'm pretty much just guessing here as I would need the website and my computer to figure it out. But is it possible the page isn't fully loaded when you attempt to `.click()` it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to:

1. Wait until this `<div id="hellopreloader"` dissapears
2. Wait until your link becomes clickable

The answer to both is [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) implemented in [Selenium Java client](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) via [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class.

Example reference code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("hellopreloader"))); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@href='#home']"))).click();
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

Comment: Nice one! so it was because it hadn't loaded yet